# Setting the cutoff frequency of an active bandpass filter (op amp) and finding the phase in LTSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, active-filter, phase-shift, cutoff-frequency

I am doing an exercise and my op amp cutoff frequencies are: lower 1kHz, upper 10kHz.

I have found the phase shift of the filter, but since the graph I get does not make much sense for me I think it is wrong.

So my questions are:

1. How can I find the phase shift? (Or am I doing it right?)
2. How to 'set' the cutoff frequencies so I get the right ones?

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: The 1 kHz and 10 kHz poles of the opamp are the frequencies you would see when the opamp is used in an **open loop** situation. Your circuit shows a closed feedback loop. It should have been explained to you how to find the open loop transfer so refer back to your study material to see how it is done.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks! I will try to do find out how to do it. It was not yet explained to me, I have to do it only as an exercise to get familiar with LTSpice and figure it on my own how to do it

Comment: "*but since the graph I get does not make much sense for me I think it is wrong"* <--  be careful with that way of expressing your thoughts, someone might think you're incredibly arrogant for dismissing a tool that's been known to accurately give results simply because "it doesn't make sense *to you*" (which surely is not the case here). Are you sure you're using the correct methodology for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic in this type of analysis but also when people using SPICE do not look at operating points. When you run ac simulations, *always* take a look at the operating or bias point calculated by the simulator. This is where small-signal analysis is performed. Should this dc operating point be wrong, then the engine delivers results which correspond to what has been given to it: garbage-in, garbage-out or GIGO applies well to this situation.

In the below picture, when you print the bias points, you see that the op-amp output in the left-case is grounded meaning the IC is not properly biased at rest. And this is normal, with a *single* supply, you need to bias the op-amp somewhere between its upper and lower stops.

[image]

In the right side, by adding a bias to the (+) input, the op-amp is now biased at a 6-V output and operates in closed-loop as it wasn't before as correctly pointed out by *Bimpelrekkie*. When you restore the bias, the below curve appears, nicely showing the op-amp limits as frequency increases:

[image]

Rather than using the 10-k resistors at the (+) pin, you could also provide another supply at the VEE pin (-12 V) now symmetrically supplying the op-amp. No additional bias would then be needed.